# Meaning of "undertakes to procure"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a contract made between company A and B:

*"Company A undertakes to procure the product requirements exclusively from company B"*

What is the meaning of that expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is English by way of Legalese (of which I have often been guilty).

In this context, [*undertake*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undertake?view=uk) means

> commit oneself to and begin (an enterprise or responsibility); take on:
>   *a firm of builders undertook the construction work*

[*Procure*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/procure) means

> *tr* to obtain or acquire; secure

In contract law, *requirements* has a special meaning. It refers to all of a company's needs for a particular product.

In Human English, the sentence means

> *Company A promises to buy all of the product it needs exclusively from company B*

Answer (score 2):

*Undertakes to procure* pretty much means *tries to get*.

You could say *endeavours to acquire*, too, if you are being paid by the letter.

But just plain *tries to get* is simplest.

Comment: I think in a contract *undertakes* means *promises, engages*.